# Send IPN to PayPal sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I have come up with a PayPal sandbox instance set up. I am able to successfully simulate a purchase, but the IPN is not being sent to the URL I have configured to listen to PayPal instant payment notification (IPN Handler). If I go to IPN Simulator on the Developer dashboard, I am able to send the IPN to the same URL handler and successfully receive it. Where do I enable IPN to the sandbox instance?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please make sure you are using PayPal IPN sample code (https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples) on your IPN handler page.
But if you still failed in receiving IPN message on Sandbox platform, please contact PayPal technical support via the link https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/app/ask/ and provide PayPal transaction ID for the further checking.

Comment: If I send an IPN via IPN Simulator I am able to receive it and properly process it. But when I perform a transaction with a simulated user, using the sandbox instance, executing the step by step of a normal purchase I am able to successfully finish the purchase, but I dont receive any IPN on my backend. As an additional information, I have included the URL on IPN setting in PayPal.